Removing multiple files from org-agenda-files
While customizing org-agenda,
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("u" "Updated Tasks"
           todo ""
           ((org-agenda-files (remove "~/org/old.org" org-agenda-files))))))

removes file ~/org/old.org from agenda files. What do I do if I want to remove multiple files, say, ~/org/old.org and ~/org/older.org from the org-agenda-files?
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("u" "Updated Tasks"
           todo ""
           ((org-agenda-files (remove "~/org/old.org" "~/org/older.org" org-agenda-files))))))

does not work.
There is a solution here. More specifically, here.
But I was wondering if I could not remove multiple files using the current approach.

What exactly do you mean by "current approach"?

You can use nested remove calls to eliminate one item at a time, or you can use a slighty more general function like -remove (from dash.el) to filter out what you don't want. Personally, I would go with the latter. Is that what you mean?

@NickD Thanks. Nesting remove did work as expected. I will add that as an answer for easy reference.

As @NickD suggested in a comment, one can nest remove calls. So, here is the solution:
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        '(("u" "Updated Tasks"
           todo ""
           ((org-agenda-files (remove "~/org/older.org" (remove "~/org/old.org" org-agenda-files)))))))

This removes older.org from a list that already had old.org removed.

For more than a couple of files I would recommend the other solution: using -remove from dash.el.
